Android emulator is not detecting in Android studio when zscaler is on in Macboook
I have installed zscaller and loggedin in my Macbook. When Zscaler on then android studio not detecting the emulator. If  off the zsclaer and restart mac again then emulator is detected by Android studio. I need run app in emulator when zscaler is on. Any help here
